# script to hold down the space bar and press keys every 10 seconds, with one key to close the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

i want create a script can hold down the space bar and press a key every 10 seconds, with one another key to close the loop but I made a mistake somewhere and I don't know how to fix it.

```
import keyboard
import time


time.sleep(8)
timer = 0
while True:  
    try: 
        while timer < 10:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            timer += 0.1
            keyboard.press('space')
        keyboard.press('z')
        timer = 0
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): 
            break     
    except:
        break
```

I dont understand why if I press `q`, it won't stop the loop.

Comment: First, maybe you should consider releasing the space key before typing "z" and releasing "z" before pressing the spacebar again ? (from my point of view if you don't release the key it cannot be pressed again) And for the 'q' key_pressed to work you should move it into the second while loop otherwise it will only work every 10 sec (then find something else than a break or it will not exit the second while loop)

Comment: is impossible hold pressed the spacebar in "background" ?

Comment: It is possible but not with the keyboard module I think. If you are on windows try the win32api and the SendMessage function that can send key and mouse input to a process even if it is in the background.